# use activity class as a fragment class from another activity dynamically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

I have some activities that extends AppCompatActivity. In my app there is a viewPager and I want some of my previous activity with their ui and functionality in this viewPager.
 How can I convert activity to fragment at runtime because I need that activities too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply make your Activity into a Fragment at runtime.

You will need to re-implement your UI using a different pattern, perhaps making the re-usable pieces of your Activity into a Fragment instead.